# move_uploaded_file() not working in my case

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

i m using wamp server with mysql and following code is added

but its not inserting file to database 
it is creating name in database creating tmp file in wamp folder but not moving it to desired directory

have look at code

```
<form  method="post" action="insert_products.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <h2>Pleaset INPUT data to Insert Into database</h2>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Title</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="ptitle"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">catagory</th>
            <td><select name="pcats">
                    <option>Select A Catagory</option>
                    <?php

                  $get_cats = "select * from catagories";
                  $query =mysqli_query($conn,$get_cats)or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($conn));
                  while($get_cats = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                      $cat_id = $get_cats['cat_id'];
                      $cat_title = $get_cats['cat_title']; 
                                         echo " <option value='$cat_id'>$cat_title</option>";
                  }
                                          ?>
                </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Brand</th>
            <td><select name="pBrands">
                    <option>Select A Brand</option>
                    <?php

                  $get_brands = "select * from brands";
                  $query =mysqli_query($conn,$get_brands)or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($conn));
                  while($get_brands = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                      $brand_id = $get_brands['brand_id'];
                      $brand_title = $get_brands['brand_title']; 
                                         echo "<option value='$brand_id'>$brand_title</option>";
                  }
                                          ?>
                </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">IMG1</th>
            <td><input type="file" name="pimg1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">IMG2</th>
            <td><input type="file" name="pimg2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">IMG3</th>
            <td><input type="file" name="pimg3"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Price</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="pprice"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">description</th>
            <td><textarea name="pdesc"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">keywords</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="pkws"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">save / Update</th>
            <td><input type="submit" name="insert_product" value="Upload / Update"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

conceptual code

....

```
      if(isset($_POST["insert_product"])){



          //  datat text variable to insert product details into database
          $pTitle = $_POST['ptitle'];
          $pCats = $_POST['pcats'];
          $pbrands = $_POST['pBrands'];
          $pPrice = $_POST['pprice'];
          $pDesc = $_POST['pdesc'];
          $pKWS = $_POST['pkws'];

          $status = 'on';       

  // product images data container to transfer images rrelated data to database
          $pIMG1 = $_FILES['pimg1']['name'];
          $pIMG2 = $_FILES['pimg2']['name'];
          $pIMG3 = $_FILES['pimg3']['name'];
          //temporary images variables
           $temp_pIMG1 = $_FILES['pimg1']['tmp_name'];
          $temp_pIMG2 = $_FILES['pimg2']['tmp_name'];
          $temp_pIMG3 = $_FILES['pimg2']['tmp_name'];

      if($pTitle == '' OR $pCats =='' OR $pbrands =='' OR $pPrice == '' OR $pDesc =='' OR $pKWS=='' or $pIMG1=='')  {
          echo "<script>alert('Please fill all the fields')</script>";
          exit();
          }else{
                $uploads_dir = APP_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. '/pro_images/';
              if(is_uploaded_file($temp_pIMG1) or is_uploaded_file($temp_pIMG2) or is_uploaded_file($temp_pIMG3) ){
          move_uploaded_file($temp_pIMG1,"$uploads_dir/$pIMG1");
              move_uploaded_file($temp_pIMG2,"$uploads_dir/$pIMG2");
          move_uploaded_file($temp_pIMG3,"$uploads_dir/$pIMG3");
              }else{
                echo"error in file upload ";

              }
          $insert_product = "INSERT INTO products (cat_id,brand_id,date,pTitle,p_Img1,p_Img2,p_Img3,p_price,p_desc,p_status) values ('$pCats','$pbrands',NOW(),'$pTitle','$pIMG1','$pIMG2','$pIMG3','$pPrice','$pDesc','$status')";
          $run_products = mysqli_query($conn,$insert_product) or die('ERROR: '.mysqli_error($conn));
          if ($run_products){
             echo " <script>alert('Inserted')</script>";
              }
          }

      }
  ?>
```

Comment: You haven't checked if the uploads actually succeeded. That's very bad. **ALWAYS** assume failure, check for it, and treat success as a pleasant surprise: `if ($_FILES['pimg1']['error']) != UPLOAD_ERR_OK) { die('upload failed'); }`

Comment: Oh, and you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: I have checked all things are going into database qwuery is okay but move_uploaded_file not moving file tem from wamp folder to my custom dire

Comment: Basically, you ignored everything Mark wrote and you moved on to typing some sort of nonsense once more. How about you read and *comprehend* what you are being advised, before replying? This whole ask a question, get an answer doesn't really work if you won't read and understand what you're being told.

Comment: If all else fails and as a last resort you could always read the manual to see how it should be done. Radical suggestion I realise, but give it a try [PHP Handling File Uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

Answer (score 0):

Check the permission for the folder you are uploading to.

It should allow writing. If its on a web server, the folder permission should be 0755

Comment: This is windows not UNIX. The `W` in `wamp` stands for `Windows`

Comment: Doesn't matter. If the folder doesn't allow writing it won't work. Just crosscheck

Answer (score 0):

Could this be the problem.

You have 2 directory seperators in the path. So try

```
$uploads_dir = APP_PATH . '/pro_images/';
```

Also I would have expected the error message to contain whatever was in APP_PATH and not the text APP_PATH. Have you actually set that to some value?

Try this while testing

```
$uploads_dir = APP_PATH . '/pro_images/';
echo '$uploads_dir = ' . $uploads_dir;
```

Answer (score 0):

hi guys thanks all of you for your support.

the only problem i found was that my browser cached wrong images location which was conflicting

more over in following line
**$uploads_dir = APP_PATH . '/pro_images/';**
i removed **APP_PATH**
the amended my code like as follow

**$uploads_dir ='./pro_images/';**

and it solved the problem one more thing before implementing this i restarted my pc.

**Thanks ALL**